# Compass not writing to style.css

Tags: phpstorm, compass-sass

SASS/Compass is not compiling from style.scss to style.css, I am working with PHPStorm's file watchers, which seems to work just fine. It notices changes in style.scss and the _mixins.scss and _variables.scss files.
When I sync the style.css (PHPStorm doesn't automatically do that), the file stays empty.

This is my config.rb:

```
css_dir = "assets/css"
sass_dir = "assets/sass"

output_style = :expanded

line_comments = true
```

The PHPStorm output shows this line of code:

```
/usr/bin/compass watch /Users/name/PhpstormProjects/imp03/inleveropdracht3/assets
```

[image: Screenshot from PHPStorm]

This is the way I have setup my file watcher.

Comment: Does it give you any errors when you try to run it? I believe you need to also have the working directory, environment vars and output paths entered. 
[See Documentation Here](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/using-file-watchers.html)

Comment: Why did you set it up like that? Why do you use `watch`? Why bundled File Watcher template is not good for you? Have you bothered to read docs? http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/working-with-sass-and-scss-in-compass-projects.html

Comment: @CJdriver I am not getting any errors, and PHPStorm is actually making a .sass-cache dir with .scssc files.

Comment: @LazyOne This is the template my professor in uni taught us to use.

Comment: Well .. your approach is very weird for me then. I may only say: the approach used in help/default template works for me in 7.1.3 on Windows. v8 Has some issues with compiling SASS/SCSS files (like http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11517 ; http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11689 etc)

Comment: I can suggest changing File watcher settings (as @LazyOne mentioned, 'standard' settings work as expected). For example, arguments: compile $ProjectFileDir$ $UnixSeparators($FilePath$), working directory: $ProjectFileDir$, output path: $ProjectFileDir$/assets/css

Comment: you have to syncronize generated file, as WebStorm has no idea where to look for output - 'output path' option is empty; also, using -watch option is redundant - file watcher already watches your files. BTW, does compass produce expected results when executing just the same command in command line?

Comment: Any solution to this? I typically just use `compass watch` in my project directory, but every one in a while, I have to do Ctrl+C and restart it to have it start writing to the main style.css again (very annoying...)